# A question on Sequences and Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to ask if a sequence can be both oscilating and increasing/ decreasing (i.e it oscillates about an increasing/ decreasing function)?

I have learnt so far that there can be a few combinations with regards to the properties of sequences ( eg: increases and converges ). Are there more combinations of these properties that sequences can have?

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest thing to do is take an oscillating function and add it to an increasing decreasing one, e.g. $f(n)=n+\sin(\pi n/3)$. The strength of the oscillation is controlled by the coefficient of the sine function.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can easily have a sequence oscillate around another sequence.  All of the following sequences oscillate around $a_n=n$ and are eventually monotonically increasing:

$$b_n=n+(-e)^{-5n}$$

$$c_n=n+\frac{\sin(n)}{n^3}$$

$$d_n=n\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right)$$

Since your second question is a little bit broad, I give you the [Wikipedia on sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence).

One property all of the sequences above have is that they are bounded, though all but the original sequence do not converge to anything.

Comment: Your sequences oscillate, but why are they increasing, as the OP asks for? $(c_n)_n$, for instance, is clearly not monotonic, having infinitely many portions on which it decreases and infinitely many on which it increases.

Comment: @AlexM. Oh, I missed that part.  My bad.